# Using Matlab Coder capi to change states at runtime

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-coder

I need to change the states of a Matlab Coder generated application at runtime.  I know I can access (and therefore change) the states of a model at runtime via CAPI.  Can I just set new values or is there something else I need to do? I am concerned that I might break the solver.

I am working on a flight model used for aircraft simulation it uses the Aerospace Block Set and some custom blocks which I use Simulink Coder to convert into C++ code.  I need to reposition and reorientation the aircraft with out stopping execution, this involves setting X, Y, Z and the quaternion values of 6DoF EOM (continuous states) and latitude and longitude on a custom block (discreet states).  I will also need to effect the velocity which means changing U V W.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: Philip I hoped my question was a good question.  I wanted to be concise and hoped a Matlab Coder expert would understand my issue.  if anyone needs further information I will gladly provide it.

Comment: I don't know about Matlab Coder, but I am familiar with C API and Simulink Coder and I don't see how you could break the solver by changing something... What exactly do you think you could break?

Comment: I think some solvers use the values of previous iterations to work out the current value.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you mean by "access and change the states of a model at runtime via CAPI"?  What sort of state are you expecting to change?  What effect do you want to achieve?  A more specific example will help the answers be specific.